# Compare 2 booleans and declare to variable

Tags: linux, bash, unix, boolean

My problem is to compare 2 booleans and declare result into variable.

```
variable=`function argument1`    # 1
variable=`$variable || function argument2`
if [ $variable == "true" ] ; then
    do one
else 
    do another
fi
```

I need to execute **function** with **argument2** and this function return **true** or **false** and need to do **OR** with **$variable** and declare result to **left variable**.

I already try different ways but don't know it possible to declare operators to variable? Thanks.

Comment: Not clear, please do let us know more details on your question.

Comment: maybe now is clear

Comment: what are you trying to do here? `variable=\`$variable || function argument2\`` is it comparing of any kind of condition check? Please be more clear on same.

Comment: yes , i need to execute function with argument2 and this function return true or false and need to do OR with $variable and declare result to left variable.

Comment: Check my solution once if that helps you to take it as a starting point of your question?